# Integral of $(1+t^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot (1+t^4)^\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving the following problem of finding the General Solution of a given ODE given below:

$$ \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} + \frac{ty}{1+t^2} = 1 - \frac{t^3y}{1+t^4}$$

I ended up with

$$y\cdot(1+t^2)^{1/2}\cdot(1+t^4)^{(1/4)} = \int (1+t^2)^{1/2}\cdot (1+t^4)^{1/4}\,\mathrm dt$$

How do I Integrate the RHS. Even online integral calculators are showing that they are unable to do it.

Can someone tell me if it is even integrable or not. Or is there any other idea of solving the ODE. Anyways I wish to learn why the integration on the RHS is not happenning. Is it non integrable?

I looked at the parabola formed by $$(1+t^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot (1+t^4)^\frac{1}{4}$$ on an online graph plotter and it looked like the area under was infinitely much as it was upward opening and a bit narrow in shape(not very).

Comment: @Community the answer I have arrived at with an integral on the RHS is basically through solving it as a Linear Differential Equation with the integrating factor being $(1+t^2)^{\frac {1}{2}}.(1+t^4)^{\frac {1}{4}}$

Comment: Is it even integrable? How do we find that out?

Comment: Sorry @arthur i did not understand. What does wolfram agree with? that it is not integrable or that it takes too much time to integrate?

Comment: What exactly makes you think that the integral has some symbolic solution? Is this task embedded in a series of similar tasks with symbolic solutions? You could try to set $u=t+t^{-1}$, then $t^2+t^{-2}=u^2-2$. But this might as well be a dead-end.

Comment: Trying Maple on this integral, I get no closed form answer, so I am guessing this integral is not an elementary function.  (The function is continuous, so of course it is "integrable".)